# C - CodeBlocks - set program's arguments

Tags: c, codeblocks

My question is pretty simple, I made a program (oil.exe) in C that applies an oil filter to an image. To make it run, I just type in the command line:

```
C:\...\oil.exe lena.ppm 5 25
```

Where the first argument is the image to edit, that is located in the same folder than oil.exe, the two last arguments are filter parameters. It works fine.

Now I want to directly launch the program from CodeBlocks, where I can set the 3 arguments in Project -> set program's arguments. My problem is that it doesn't work, the program fails to open the file while I am typing my arguments exactly in the same way :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdXkd.png)

Am I doing a mistake somewhere ?

Comment: Might be a difference in the working directory when you run from the IDE.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Please post the image not a link to it. Are you sure you are testing the release target?

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your quick answers ! Moving the image in the project directory worked.

Comment: By default, when your create a Code::Blocks project, the default working directory is the folder where your cbp file exists.

Answer (score 0):

The current working directory is maybe not the directory your `oil.exe` and `lena.ppm` are in but the project directory. Try placing the picture there or specify the full path.